# Valor nuevo o el anterior en script de acuerdo a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, entrada

Necesito que cuando `"nuevo_saldo"` sea igual a cero: el valor de `"restan"` sea también cero. Pero... si no fuera así, **conserve su valor inicial**.

**EDITADO:**
Gracias a una respuesta oportuna (@alanfcm) se logro un avance en este problema, solo persiste (posiblemente me llamen quisquilloso, pero pienso en la forma optima que debe trabajar el usuario final) un *pequeño* problema.

Cuando el valor de `"restan"` es igual a cero gracias a que `"importe"` logro cubrir a `"restan"` todo *estaría bien*. Pero realmente el usuario final (en una de sus equivocaciones o cambios) tendría que poder poner otra cantidad en `"importe"` y poder realizar la operación inicial sin que fuera el valor cero que se genero por su "error o cambio".

¿Alguna idea de como poder hacerlo? Aun pienso en la creación de un nuevo campo `hidden`que pudiera cubrir este punto, ¿Que opinan?

Gracias de antemano.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function operacion_resta() {
    var uno, dos, tres, operacion;
    uno = $('#importe');
    dos = $('#restan');
    tres = $('#nuevo_saldo');
    operacion = parseFloat(dos.val()) - parseFloat(uno.val());
    tres.val(operacion);
    if (tres.val() == "0") {
      $('#restan').val('0');
    }
  }

  $("#importe").keyup(function() {
    var dos;
    dos = $('#restan').val();
    if (dos != "") {
      operacion_resta()
    }
  });

  $('#nuevo_saldo').change(function() {
    var dos, tres;
    tres = $('#nuevo_saldo').val();
    if (tres == "0") {
      dos = $('#restan').val('0');
    } else {

    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" id="restan" name="restan" value="800"><br>
  <label> Realmente es de tipo "hidden" pero para valores prácticos (ver resultados) aquí sera de tipo "text".</label>
</div>
<label>------------------------------------------------</label>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="importe">Importe: *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="importe" placeholder="$0" name="importe" required>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="nuevo_saldo">Su nuevo saldo es:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nuevo_saldo" placeholder="$0" name="nuevo_saldo" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer el cambio en tu funcion operacion_resta() asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function operacion_resta() {
    var uno, dos, tres, operacion;
    uno = $('#importe');
    dos = $('#restan');
    tres = $('#nuevo_saldo');
    operacion = parseFloat(dos.val()) - parseFloat(uno.val());
    tres.val(operacion);
    if (tres.val() == "0") {
      $('#restan').val('0');
    }
  }

  $("#importe").keyup(function() {
    var dos;
    dos = $('#restan').val();
    if (dos != "") {
      operacion_resta()
    }
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" id="restan" name="restan" value="800"><br>
  <label> Realmente es de tipo "hidden" pero para valores prácticos (ver resultados) aquí sera de tipo "text".</label>
</div>
<label>------------------------------------------------</label>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="importe">Importe: *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="importe" placeholder="$0" name="importe" required>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="nuevo_saldo">Su nuevo saldo es:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nuevo_saldo" placeholder="$0" name="nuevo_saldo" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cierto, es funcional y agradezco mucho tu respuesta, pero tengo un detalle, esto cubre sola la mitad del problema.
Ya que si realmente, no se desea borrar lo que existe en `restan` lo mas común seria editar `importe` pero como se sobrescribió ya no podría deshacer ese cambio.

Comment: Si tu input es de tipo hidden, entonces no necesitas hacer el cambio hasta que estes seguro.  O sea hasta que el usuario guarde los datos o submitas tu forma.

Comment: Es muy cierto, pero pensaba mas como el usurio final (Y en mi jefe reclamando jeje) pero para que complicarse la vida y mejor dejarlo así. Gracias nuevamente :D